# Наследование от главного класса и работа в одном окне

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, arcade

Разбираюсь с ООП. Создал меню игры "Battle City".

При нажатии на кнопку в окне - создаётся новое окно, мне необходимо оставаться только в одном объекте (окне), в классе MainMenu, заменяя лишь контент внутри него (главное меню -> 1 лвл -> 2 лвл...).

Файл `main.py`:

```
import arcade
import level_one
from constans import SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE, AMOUNT_PLAYERS


class MainMenu(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        super().__init__(width, height, title)
        self.yellow_tank = Tank()
        self.main_menu = arcade.load_texture('images/main_menu2.png')

        ...
        ...
        ...

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        global AMOUNT_PLAYERS

        ...


        if key == arcade.key.ENTER and self.yellow_tank.center_y == 410:
            # print('Один игрок')
            AMOUNT_PLAYERS = 1

        elif key == arcade.key.ENTER and self.yellow_tank.center_y == 363:
            # print('Два игрока')
            AMOUNT_PLAYERS = 2
            level_one.LevelOne(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)  # ПРОБЛЕМА


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MainMenu(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()
```

А также `level_one.py`:

```
import arcade
import main
from main import MainMenu
from constans import SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE


class LevelOne(main.MainMenu):
    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        super().__init__(width, height, title)
        print('hello')
        self.main_menu = arcade.load_texture('images/main_menu.jpg')

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.draw_texture_rectangle(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, self.main_menu)
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как работать исключительно в одном окне между разными модулями?

Comment: Я не понял, что требуется. Может геймеры поймут, но советую яснее написать, что не работает, и что нужно.  "не понимаю как работать исключительно в одном окне" - нужно объяснить, как работать, например? "окно остаётся неизменчивым" - это проблема? И т.д.

Comment: @Сергей есть main.py - там находится меню, пользователь нажимает на кнопочку и переходит в level_one.py, работа должна происходить в одном окне, без создания нового объекта. У меня создаётся отдельное окно

Comment: Павел, советую исправить текст самого вопроса, и задать его до кода, чтобы людям не искать.

Comment: @Сергей спасибо, готово!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы создаете два окна. У вас `LevelOne` и `MainMenu` наследуются от `Window` и вы создаете по экземпляру каждого класса. Потому и показывается два окна. Сейчас структура классов такая:

[image: Диаграмма классов - сейчас]

Она неправильная, так как `LevelOne` и `MainMenu` не должны быть окнами.

Нужно это изменить и сделать, чтоб был только один экземпляр окна. Имеет смысл создать его один раз и чтоб он вызывал обработчики (делегировал обработку) текущему "екрану" (это я так назвал, но вы можете назвать, как вам кажется более подходящим).  Тут (как и во всем ООП) важно:

1. разделить обязанности между классами.
2. один класс должен отвечать за одну вещь

Например, окно программы (см. класс `MainWindow`), по моему, не должно знать о деталях игры, т.е. например, что существуют какие-то танки. Я бы сделал его ответственным только за делегирование сообщений текущему екрану. Структура [может](https://www.planttext.com/?text=ZL4nRi904Ept5LVQXN-08fGQb88YvMbrjuAJdJMwFR0GqAHDIZv2GuFW3USVnOujC4eAgjqRxTpCx8ube0-hZm8aTwnyAGGGN2X8nKEyndCynKkygdYil-hF-XjWYIR7EIdq1YsfBPW2HTIxOrjMi8V-FKN77TQCbAnpskYb9v6awT8MiHwh90MfN30B7KejnXDnqXNjR7h_RVQBlQAqWaynMlqfyQfZTXvwnRzkRgm9hQbuOtgMrISSxRAcS3P83OC5ZBANGG8OX7aWtkt-E_Be3G36nBQvt0y0) быть такая:

[image: диаграмма классов]

В коде это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
# main_window.py
class MainWindow(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self, width, height, title, screens, current_screen):
        self.screens = {screen.__class__:screen for screens in screens}
        self.current_screen = current_screen

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        return self.current_screen.on_key_press(key, modifires)

    def on_draw(self):
        return self.current_screen.on_draw()

    def switch_to_screen(self, screen_id):
        self.current_screen = screens[screen_id]

class ScreenBase:
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        self.main_window = main_window

    def switch_to_screen(self, screen_id):
        self.main_window.switch_to_screen(screen_id)

# level_one.py

class LevelOneScreen(main_window.ScreenBase):
    def __init__(self, main_menu_screen_id):
        self.main_menu_screen_id = main_menu_screen_id
        ...

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.draw_texture_rectangle(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, self.main_menu)

# main_menu.py

class MainMenuScreen(main_window.ScreenBase):
    def __init__(self, level_one_screen_id):
        self.level_one_screen_id = level_one_screen_id
        ...

    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        global AMOUNT_PLAYERS

        ...


        if key == arcade.key.ENTER and self.yellow_tank.center_y == 410:
            # print('Один игрок')
            AMOUNT_PLAYERS = 1

        elif key == arcade.key.ENTER and self.yellow_tank.center_y == 363:
            # print('Два игрока')
            AMOUNT_PLAYERS = 2
            self.switch_to_screen(level_one_screen_id)

# main.py

SCREENS = [MainMenuScreen(LevelOneScreen), LevelOneScreen(MainMenuScreen)]
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = MainWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE,
      SCREENS, MainMenuScreen)
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()
```

Comment: спасибо большое за крутой ответ! На деле ясна логика, но ещё около суток я разбирался что к чему)) по вашему объяснению составляю дальше пет-проектик и уже доделываю второй уровень. Прошу прощения за задержку и ещё раз спасибо❤️